# Change url doesn't change tab selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, local-storage

I was implementing that if i refresh the page, it should make active to previously selected tab(preserve selected tab) . So I Create a simple html page and add some jQuery.
But if i change URL manually  like `file:///home/2.html#news` to `file:///home/2.html#home`

it changes only content of page but doesn't change tab ,that was selected. .

Here is my code.

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li id="first"><a  href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li id="second"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li id="third"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li id="forth"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p id="home">
        home section
    </p>
    <p id="news">
        news section
    </p>
    <p id="contact">
        contact section
    </p>
    <p id="about">
        about section
    </p>
</body>
   <style>
    p{
    display: none;
    }
    :target {
    display:block;
        border: 2px solid #D4D4D4;
        background-color: #e5eecc;

    }
   </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(localStorage.getItem("active_state") == null ){
            activeStateId = "first";
        }
        else{
            activeStateId = localStorage.getItem("active_state")
        }
        $('#'+activeStateId).addClass('active');
        $('li').click(function(){
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            localStorage.setItem("active_state", $(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Probably need to run this page on a server. localStorage is domain specific and probably not even available when you use file protocol (not sure though). If you don't already have a localhost server set up it is easy to do and there are lots of ways to run one ..all easily researched. Web development is rarely done using file protocol as there are other restrictions such as no ajax

Comment: thanks @charlietfl for answer. but how can I do this by creating a simple html .

Comment: @TheVinspro You probably can't. I think there is a flag that you can launch Chrome with, that removes some restrictions on file protocol, but generally speaking, it is better to either use a local server, as charlietfl suggested, or use a development tool that makes on for you automatically, like WebStorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you got link hashes, you dont actually reload the page, but the browser just triggers those links. You rely on CSS `:target` change rule which evaluates every time the `#hash` changes on the url.

```
p {
    display: none;
}

:target {
    display:block;
    border: 2px solid #D4D4D4;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
}
```

Thus, you have all the sections updated properly even without refreshing the page. In order to have such functionality, you don't need to store any data to the local or remote machine since you are using hashes on the url. Just use the hashes and handle the `hashchange` event to add the `.activate` class to the links like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    if(hash.length > 0) {
        hash = hash.substring(1);
        $('li a[href$='+hash+']').parent().addClass('active');
    }

    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        var hash = window.location.hash
        if(hash.length > 0) {
            hash = hash.substring(1);
            $('li a[href$='+hash+']').parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Check my working example here: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/urlhash.html#about

Comment: @TheVinspro glad my answer is working for you. Please mark it as the accepted answer if it helped you. To see how you can mark an answer as accepted, please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).